# Synthesis Golf I: Sodium Fluvastatin

Tags: synthesis-golf

[A full FAQ exists on meta.chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/synthesis-golf-faq) explaining the premise of synthesis golf, why we're doing this, and the ground rules. Please read this *before* posting an answer.

The target for this first round of synthesis golf is sodium fluvastatin, an artificial statin drug used to treat hypercholesterolemia and in the prevention of cardiovascular disease. You must provide a synthetic route to the target molecule.

[image: Sodium Fluvastatin - Synthesis Golf I]

In addition, to narrow the scope of this question:

- the synthesis must include a way of making the indole (i.e. no buying of the indole core and carrying out multiple functionalisation reactions).
- all of the stereo centres must be set. Relative stereochemistry only is fine (the 1,3-*syn* relationship between the hydroxyls), but if you can think of a way to set them with absolute configuration, then great.

Comment: This is a neat idea - hopefully there are enough experts in organic synthesis on the site to make for a robust set of answers.

Comment: (may/may not be helpful to anyone but this doesn't cost me much) **SMILES for target molecule** `O=C(C[C@H](C[C@H](/C=C/C(N1C(C)C)=C(C2=CC=CC=C21)C3=CC=C(F)C=C3)O)O)O` and **InChI** `InChI=1S/C24H26FNO4/c1-15(2)26-21-6-4-3-5-20(21)24(16-7-9-17(25)10-8-16)22(26)12-11-18(27)13-19(28)14-23(29)30/h3-12,15,18-19,27-28H,13-14H2,1-2H3,(H,29,30)/b12-11+/t18-,19-/m0/s1`

Comment: This is so interesting! Can't we fully adopt this idea and create a new stack exchange like the code golf?

Comment: @KartikeyaBadola you would need to have sufficient interest, if these become popular then it might be a consideration. See: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Is the idea to find a route with fewer steps than previously published routes? Or are people supposed to answer without consulting previous works?

Comment: @DavePhD Was intended to be a back-of-the-envelope type of thing, else people won't answer anyway because it takes too much time/effort, but SciFinder etc is fair game (i.e. its not necessarily intended to be done blind).  The idea was really just the shortest/most efficient synthesis from users on here (i.e. not comparing to a process route which has undoubtedly had many rounds of optimisation).

Comment: What are the precise criteria for "shortest route"? The number of nominal steps in the mechanism? The number of experimental steps involved?

Comment: Are we back to arguing about what a step is? (@hBy2Py: you may be interested http://openflask.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/11-step-synthesis-of-thapsigargin.html)

Comment: Maybe put a limit on the adjusted cost per kilo or cost per mole to eliminate some advanced intermediates that are readily available? I.e. To make it more commercially realistic?

Comment: @orthocresol Well, ***I've*** never argued about what a step is, so this particular party's all new to me. :-P

Comment: This is quite a good idea. Even this question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75283/how-to-convert-carboxylic-acid-into-an-alkene could be a potential synthesis golf.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal - theres definitely some refining to do to make the problem easy enough to be answered and hard enough to be interesting. The linked question possibly borders on the tedious, a SciFinder search would instantly reveal every published way of doing that transformation, there isn't really much room for creativity.        I encourage you to take a shot at the current problem though!

Comment: @NotBaran I wanted to, unfortunately I don't know how to create an Indole ring .

Comment: @PrittBalagopal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole#Synthetic_routes   Wikipedia has articles on the most common if you're interested :)

Comment: @NotBaran Hmm, this looks good. I'll give a shot after doing some scrap workouts. 

Comment: I recommend a creating #synthesis-golf tag.

Comment: @zhe. I was planning on posting in meta to ask people for thoughts/opinions first. I think it's been interesting and kind of successful but if it was to become a thing it possibly has to be done in an organised way

Comment: This is a great idea. I am sad I've missed this. When will the next problem be posted?

Comment: @Marko... next Monday, and then one a month as per https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/synthesis-golf-faq/3789#3789

Comment: I don't like the frequency. A problem per two weeks would be much better.

Comment: @Marko, there has to be a balance. If the challenges get a sensible number of responses in two weeks then it can perhaps happen more frequently. I think the concern is that too frequent and they go unanswered...

Comment: I am certain that they wouldn't be unanswered. After all, this question had excellent reception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Edit:** step count is 15, longest linear sequence of 9 steps

Just to (hopefully) get the ball rolling, here's something I scribbled down. I am sure people here will have better answers. And I have not done a lot of literature research to see whether the steps are plausible, so there might be fatal flaws... but hopefully not; as far as I know/can tell, everything here is relatively sensible.

Retrosynthesis first. I chose a [Horner–Wadsworth–Emmons reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%E2%80%93Wadsworth%E2%80%93Emmons_reaction) to make the (*E*)-double bond, and something similar to the [Reissert synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissert_indole_synthesis) for the indole. It's not exactly the same because I didn't acylate the benzylic carbon, but the initial disconnection is similar. This leads to the key building blocks:

[image: Retrosynthesis 1]

I chose the C(sp<sup>2</sup>)-C(sp<sup>3</sup>) bonds in **2** to disconnect. One can be made by S<sub>N</sub>Ar with the amazing S<sub>N</sub>Ar substrate 1-fluoro-2-nitrobenzene (**5**), and the other by Pd cross-coupling (I'm guessing cheaper ways probably exist). I've never actually seen S<sub>N</sub>Ar reactions with enolates as nucleophiles, but I guess that if it doesn't work, S<sub>RN</sub>1-type conditions should still make that step possible:

[image: Retrosynthesis 2]

As for **3**, I figured it could be made from a symmetrical intermediate:

[image: Retrosynthesis 3]

---

### Forward synthesis

Synthesis of **3**, starting from cyclopentadiene:

[image: Forward synthesis 1]

> (i) $\ce{BH3.THF}$, then $\ce{H2O2, NaOH}$; (ii) TBSCl, imidazole; (iii) $\ce{O3}$, then $\ce{H2O2}$; (iv) $\ce{TMSCHN2}$; (v) enzymatic desymmetrisation (I did not look up specifically which, but I think it should be possible); (vi) **7**, NaH

Next, the synthesis of **2**, starting from methylglyoxal:

[image: Forward synthesis 2]

> (vii) ethylene glycol, TsOH; (viii) Pd cat., ligand, $\ce{NaO^{t}Bu}$, **6**; (ix) NaH, **5**

Forming the indole:

[image: Forward synthesis 3]

> (x) Zn, AcOH; (xi) $\ce{NaH, ^{i}PrI}$; (xii) aq. HCl

and finally the HWE, the TBS deprotection, and the last redox step, a [diastereoselective boron reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasaka%E2%80%93Prasad_reduction). I wasn't entirely sure if it would work on an α,β-unsaturated ketone, but [Comp Org Synth II, section 8.01](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780080977423008016) has several examples of it being used on an α,β-unsaturated ketones.

[image: Forward synthesis 4]

> (xiii) LiHMDS, **3**; (xiv) $\ce{TBAF, H2O}$; (xv) $\ce{Et2B(OMe), NaBH4}$

Comment: Would the conversion from cyclopentadiene to the other compound work? I think cyclopentadiene is quite reactive, and undergoes a Diels-Alder reaction with itself.

Comment: You buy the Diels-Alder adduct (http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/substance/dicyclopentadiene132207773611?lang=en&region=GB), then heat it to get the monomer (e.g. http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV4P0238); you can use the monomer in further reactions. Wikipedia article has more info.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about your synthesis of compound **4**. Methylglyoxal, being rather unstable in its pure form, is typically sold as a 40% solution in water, which would make acetal formation (and concomitant removal of water) rather difficult. Additionally, the formation of the acetal with TosOH and ethylene glycol would probably not proceed smoothly, likely forming the diacetal and some polymeric material. Methylglyoxal 1,1-dimethyl acetal is commercially available from Sigma-Aldrich, and avoids this problem (and saves a step).

Comment: @JSK thanks! That's much more tractable. I've not done a lot of stuff in the lab yet - so my practical knowledge will be rather limited too. On paper I suppose it would be possible to selectively protect the aldehyde over the ketone, but I realise that in practice it's going to be an entirely different matter.

Comment: @orthocresol no problem! I did like your use of hydroboration on cyclopentadiene; I wasn't sure of the regioselectivity on cyclic dienes, but it appears to be quite regioselective in modest yields. It seems like most syntheses of cyclopent-3-en-1-ol use either epoxidation of cyclopentadiene, followed by lithium aluminium hydride reduction, or use a metathesis reaction on hepta-1,6-dien-4-ol, but your method works nicely as a single step (in my opinion, but at least single pot) reaction from a simple starting material.

Answer (score 15):

### Strategy

The indole core can be made with one of numerous methods; having had classes taught by Dr. Richard Larock, my first inclination was to use the Larock indole synthesis. The Larock indole synthesis uses an *N*-alkylated/acylated/tosylated 2-iodoanilines and a di-substituted alkyne to produce 1,2,3-trisubstituted indoles in one step. However, care must be taken to ensure appropriate regioselectivity of the product. The use of a TMS-substituted phenylacetylene produces a 2-trimethylsilyl-3-phenylindole (Larock, JOC, **1998**, *63* (22), 7652).

The main complexity of the molecule is found in the side-chain, containing a syn-1,3-diol with alkene and carboxylate functionality; installation of a chiral alcohol $\beta$ to a ketone would allow diastereoselective formation of the diol.

### Synthesis

The side chain may be made in a few steps from the cheap and commercially available 2,2,6-trimethyl-4H-1,3-dioxin-4-one (**1**), which is first deprotonated and reacted with TMSCl to produce compound **2**. A Mukaiyama aldol-type reaction, mediated by a titanium (IV) compound, e.g. titanium tetrachloride or Ti(OiPr)$_3$Cl, between **2** and acrolein produces the racemic alcohol **3**.

Refluxing **3** in methanol and toluene with catalytic pTSA removes the acetal-like protecting group to form the methyl $\beta$-ketoester **4**. The Narasaka–Prasad reduction on **4** uses the boron reagent diethylmethoxyborane (available from Sigma-Aldrich) as a chelating reagent to permit the diastereoselective reduction with sodium borohydride to the alkenyldiol **5** (relative stereochemistry is shown).

It should be noted that the aldol reaction to produce **3** may also be performed enantioselectively, as in Singer and Carreira, JACS **1995**, *117*, 12360, to give the desired enantiomeric alcohol; compound **4** retains this stereochemistry, and the diol **5** would then be the single diastereomer shown. Alternatively, chiral resolution could be performed at this point, or the racemic compound could be used to produce racemic Fluvastatin.

[image]

As the Larock indole synthesis allows for the use of a 2-iodoaniline and a trimethylsilyl phenylacetylene derivative, the main core is synthesised using this reaction. A palladium- and copper-catalyzed Sonogashira coupling between 1-bromo-4-fluorobenzene (**6**) and ethynyltrimethylsilane gives the TMS-substituted 4-fluorophenylacetylene **7**. Meanwhile, *N*-isopropyl-2-iodoaniline (**9**) is synthesized from 2-iodoaniline (**8**, from Sigma-Aldrich) and acetone via formation of the imine in acetic acid, followed by the *in situ* reduction with sodium triacetoxyborohydride.

The palladium-catalyzed Larock indole synthesis is then used to produce indole **10** from alkyne **7** and aniline **9**. The 2-TMS-substituted indole is capable of undergoing a Heck reaction (see Larock, JOC, **1998**, *63* (22), 7652) with alkenyldiol **5** to form **11**, the methyl ester of Fluvastatin. Ester hydrolysis with sodium hydroxide in water gives the sodium carboxylate, Fluvastatin, **12**, in nine steps.

Answer (score 11):

I thought given the challenge, it was only fair that I 'wasted' some time thinking about this myself. The following route is hopefully plausible, even if not 100% thought through. Comments welcomed, and hopefully provides some competition to Ortho's great attempt.

---

#### Strategy and retrosynthesis

The synthesis proposed here disconnects fluvastatin into two main components: an indole core, and a side chain containing the stereocentres.

Fragment union is proposed to take place via [selective cross metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olefin_metathesis) (mainly because @Orthocresol made use of [a HWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%E2%80%93Wadsworth%E2%80%93Emmons_reaction) and I thought some variety would be nice [though seriously, cross metathesis is great for not having to use pre-functionalised precursors]).

The indole core itself is proposed to be brought together using a modern variant of a [Bischler Indole synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bischler%E2%80%93M%C3%B6hlau_indole_synthesis) by cyclisation of a linear precursor under L.A. conditions, avoiding the potential regioselectivity issues of many indole syntheses involving carbonyl condensations.

For the side-chain, a vinylogous [Mukaiyama aldol reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukaiyama_aldol_addition) should provide the required stereochemistry, using a copper-bisoxazoline catalyst to control the absolute facial selectivity.

---

#### Synthesis of the Indole core

Starting from commercially available fluorobenzene **1** (Aldrich: 500G/16.30GBP) a Friedel Crafts acylation using the ethylene glycol (Aldrich: 1000mL/52.60GBP) derived acyl chloride in the presence of a Lewis acid catalyst could be carried out to give the acylated ring **2**. Regioselectivity of the Friedel-Crafts is well precedented based on directing effects of the fluorine, with the 4-position both activated electronically and sterically most accessible. Due to the availability of the starting materials, poor regioselectivity at this stage not crucial, and the isomers *could* be separated.

Subsequent cleavage of the PMB under oxidative conditions furnishes the free alcohol **3** which may undergo an [Appel-type iodination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appel_reaction) (could also do a Finkelstein via formation of the tosylate), displacement, and reductive amination with acetone to provide the indole precursor **6**.

Upon treatment with a Lewis acid catalyst and heat, **6** *should* undergo (what I think I can call) a [Bischler indole synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bischler%E2%80%93M%C3%B6hlau_indole_synthesis) to furnish the indole core of fluvastatin **7**, via this method no regioselectivity issues arise, since the two reacting partners are tethered together, with only the 5 membered ring being favoured.

Failing the milder Lewis acidic conditions, polyphosphoric acid (PPA) is common, and given the lack of delicate functionality in the molecule, this should pose no issue.
[image: Indole core synthesis of Fluvastatin Sodium]

---

#### Completion of the synthesis

With the indole core **7** in hand, functionality must be installed at the 2-position. Standard [Vilsmeyer-Haack conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilsmeier%E2%80%93Haack_reaction) afford aldehyde **8** which may undergo [Tebbe olefination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebbe%27s_reagent) (or similar) to provide a terminal olefin **9** capable of undergoing (E) [selective cross metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olefin_metathesis) with side chain **18** (synthesis described below). Final ester saponification using NaOH provides the sodium salt of Fluvastatin **11**.

[image]

#### Stereoselective synthesis of the side-chain

---

The crucial step of this synthesis is the setting of the 1,3-*syn* diol with complete absolute and relative stereochemistry.

Chan's diene **12** has been shown to undergo enantio- and diastereo-selective [Mukaiyama aldol reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukaiyama_aldol_addition) to furnish the 1,3-*syn* diol **13** using a copper-bisoxazoline catalyst. Protection of the diol as the acetonide, reductive debenzylation, [DMP oxidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dess%E2%80%93Martin_periodinane) and [Tebbe olefination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebbe%27s_reagent) then affords the required terminal olefin **18** for the planned cross metathesis.

[image]

---

#### Conclusion

Based on the proposed synthesis, Fluvastatin Sodium **11** would be synthesised in 19 steps overall, with 13 steps in the longest linear sequence.

Comment: Why not do the acylation of fluorobenzene with chloroacetyl chloride?

Comment: I wasn't confident which chloribe would get ripped off first by the Lewis acid - I'm sure there's precedence, I just would take my chances

Comment: Org. Syn. Coll. Vol 3, 191        4-F-phenacyl chloride is commercially available

Comment: I admittedly forgot about the existence of Vilsmeier formylation. Regarding the Mukaiyama, does that produce the diol in one step? All I can find is Evans' report on it, where he used $\ce{Me4NBH(OAc)3}$ to reduce the beta-hydroxyketone to the anti diol: [*JACS* **1996,** *118,* 5814](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja960712i) P/S Did you use ChemDraw for this?

Comment: @orthocresol. The Vilsmeyer is an old'un but has its uses.  I think I might have mis-read a step for the aldol (will correct shortly)- it likely just needs a Narasaka afterwards. It is ChemDraw, the settings have just been significantly changed (thicker lines, shorter bond lengths)

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm just curious as to what font that is?

Comment: Frutiger (Frutiger Neue to be precise IIRC).

Comment: So the conversion of 1 to 4 is one step depending on how much of a purist one wants to be vs the phenacyl bromide

Comment: As a compromise to being a synthetic purist and buying the phenacyl bromide, you could also start with 4'-fluoroacetophenone and perform a bromination to compound 4 as per Org. Synth. 1939, 19, 24.

Answer (score 8):

Reference through step 2: [Synthesis of carbon–14 labeled fluvastatin](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1099-1344(199801)41:1%3C1::AID-JLC52%3E3.0.CO;2-B/abstract), *Journal of Labeled Compounds and Radiopharmaceuticals* volume 41, pages 1-7.

Step 0 (product is commercially available):

Fluorobenzene + [Bromoacetylchloride](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/16120?lang=en&region=US) $\ce{->}$ [2-Bromo-4′-fluoroacetophenone](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/389390?lang=en&region=US)

(Aluminum chloride, 75 °C)

Step 1:

[2-Bromo-4′-fluoroacetophenone](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/389390?lang=en&region=US) + [N-Isopropylaniline](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/124478?lang=en&region=US) $\ce{->}$ [1-(4-fluorophenyl)-2-[(1-methylethyl)phenylamino]-ethanone](http://www.chemnet.com/cas/en/93957-51-8/.html) $\ce{->}$ [3-(4-Fluorophenyl)-1-isopropyl-1H-indole](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB5781155.htm)

(intermediate created under nitrogen atmosphere, ethanol solvent, 78 °C, 1 hour.  Intermediate then reacted with zinc chloride, ethanol solvent).

Step 2:
 [3-(4-Fluorophenyl)-1-isopropyl-1H-indole](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB5781155.htm) +  [N-methyl-N-phenyl-3-amino acrolein](http://www.alfa-chemistry.com/cas_14189-82-3.htm) $\ce{->}$ [3-[3-(4-Fluorophenyl)-1-isopropyl-1H-indol-2-yl]-propenal](https://www.scbt.com/scbt/product/e-3-3-4-fluorophenyl-1-isopropyl-1h-indol-2-yl-propenal-93957-50-7)

(nitrogen atmosphere, phosphorous oxychloride, acetonitrile solvent)

Then see [Facile and Highly Enantioselective Synthesis of (+)- and (−)-Fluvastatin and Their Analogues](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo101542y) *Journal of Organic Chemistry*, volume 75, pages 7514–7518.

Step 3:

[3-[3-(4-Fluorophenyl)-1-isopropyl-1H-indol-2-yl]-propenal](https://www.scbt.com/scbt/product/e-3-3-4-fluorophenyl-1-isopropyl-1h-indol-2-yl-propenal-93957-50-7) + [diketene](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/302058?lang=en&region=US) $\ce{->}$ 3-[3-(4-Fluorophenyl)-1-(1-methylethyl)-1H-indol-2-yl]-5-hydroxy-3-oxo-(6E)-heptenoic acid-1-isopropyl ester

(in the presence of [Ti(O-i-Pr)4](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/205273?lang=en&region=US) and chiral Schiff base, -40 °C, methylene chloride)

Step 4: reduction of ketone with $\ce{NaBH4}$ to yield [fluvastatin isopropyl ester](https://www.lgcstandards.com/BR/en/Fluvastatin-Isopropyl-Ester/p/MM0676.11)

Step 5: saponification to yield fluvastatin product.

(Step 6: preparation of the chiral Schiff base from [3-tert-Butyl-2-hydroxybenzaldehyde](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/481874?lang=en&region=US) and [valinol](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/94672?lang=en&region=US))

---

For alternatives to steps 3-6, see [An Improved Manufacturing Process for Fluvastatin](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/op060191b) *Organic Process Research & Development* volume 11, pages 13-18.

And for alternatives generally see:

Section 9.1 of [Fluvastatin](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/fluvastatin#section=Top) in Pubchem

US patents  [4739073](http://www.google.com/patents/US4739073) and [5354772](http://www.google.com/patents/US5354772)

[Cardiovascular Drugs](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14356007.a05_289.pub2/abstract) in Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry.

Answer (score 6):

I'm stuck with the lateral chain, but here are my two cents for the formation of the indole with just a few steps/reagents (I admit I'm quite a newbie, yet an enthusiast in organic chemistry).

Maybe help is not admitted, but I hope my idea could be integrated by others:

Sigma-Aldrich has readily available the p-fluorophenylacetic acid.

A typical Fischer synthesis for the indole might be performed with said compound and (the diazonium salt of) aniline.

The product is brominated with $\ce{PBr3}$. This results in 2-bromo-3-(4-fluorophenyl)-1H-indole

The amine might be alkylated by reaction with a 2-halopropane.

A Grignard reagent could then be formed, and by reaction with a haloalkene, a Kumada reaction could attach the side chain. Yet, I admit that I didn't come up with a decent way of preserving the stereochemistry of the side chain.

"Ai posteri l'ardua sentenza"

Answer (score 2):

A synthesis which involves an Evans auxiliary to induce asymmetry, and a Narasaka-Prasad reduction to control diastereoselectivity.

[image][image]